# How to make text align vertically even when window size changes

Tags: html, css

How to make text align like this, even if the window size changes?
[image: text align according to the top]

Basically all the text bellow the red text must align perfectly with the red text

Comment: can you share a snippet of what you have so far?

Comment: maybe if you use fixed columns value in %, also, set a min-width !

Comment: Shared what I ve done so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the luxury of being able to use grid, then sub-grid is designed exactly for this use case. If not, I would recommend using a table. The data looks rather 'tabular' and it's a good use of table.

For a quick conceptual understanding of Subgrid, I refer you to this post: https://dev.to/kenbellows/why-we-need-css-subgrid-53mh

Comment: Table did the job thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can do this for the parent element

```
.parent{
      position: relative;    
}
```

and this for the child element

```
.child{
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

'display: flex;'
'align-items: center;'
'justify-content: center;'

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line in the head section of your HTML code:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

and this at the bottom of your CSS code:
the number between the braces equals the maximum screen size for your CSS to take effect

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){ //any CSS here is to make it snap into place based on how the window size affects it }
```

//if you need another window size

```
@media screen and (max-width: 200px) { //make another one }
```